# Discord.py music bot not working properly and creates an error

Tags: python, discord.py

Hello I am trying to create a music bot for my discord server. However when I try to play music the error was

```
query "song: Failed to parse JSON  (caused by JSONDecodeError('Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)')); please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.
```

Here is the code :

```
@commands.command()
    async def play(self, ctx: commands.Context, url: str, *args: str):
        

        music_queue = self.music_queues[ctx.guild]
        voice = get(self.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

        try:
            channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        except:
            await ctx.send('You\'re not connected to a voice channel.')
            return

        if voice is not None and not self.client_in_same_channel(ctx.message.author, ctx.guild):
            await ctx.send('You\'re not in my voice channel.')
            return

        if not url.startswith('https://'):
            url = f'ytsearch1:{url} {" ".join(args)}'

        try:
            song = Song(url, author=ctx.author)
        except SongRequestError as e:
            await ctx.send(e.args[0])
            return

        music_queue.append(song)
        await ctx.send(f'Queued song: {song.title}')

        if voice is None or not voice.is_connected():
            await channel.connect()

        await self.play_all_songs(ctx.guild)
```

It had worked properly before, and I don't know where I should put the verbose. Youtube-dl is updated and I have installed all the packages. I am using repl.it to edit the code.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Well, it literally says it's a bug in the error message, so you might just have to wait until they fix it. Make sure you are on the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too experienced with Python, but as a suggestion, did you make sure the JSON file is properly referred to (linked or whatever it's called) as a source at the beginning of the file, and that the JSON is properly imported and written to? It seems to be that your code is unable to read the JSON file containing the information, so you may want to double-check using a simple youtube tutorial that all your code is written properly in that file, as they are pretty helpful; even for experienced coders.
It may also be helpful to update your discord.py as that can become outdated and keep in mind that some commands that may have worked in a previous version of discord.py, may not work in the newer versions.

Comment: It had worked two days ago, and it was working fine without a JSON file.